# Voltar a tela ANTERIOR sem perder "INFORMAÇÕES" da tela anterior

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho a Tela 01, faço uma busca e retorno o resultado na propria tela. Cada linha do resultado retornado contem um botão.

O botão me remete a TELA 02. Na tela 02 faço uma busca e os valores da busca são retornados na propria TELA 02. Cada linha retornada do resultado contem um botão.

Gostaria de clicar neste botão da TELA 02 e retorna a TELA 01 JÁ COM O RESULTADO DA PESQUISA DA TELA 01 FEITO (PASSO 02).

Abaixo posto imagens para TENTAR ilustrar a sequencia e resultado pretendido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clico no botão e faço a pesquisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clico no botão MARCAR e vou para a TELA 02:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clico NA BUSCA da TELA 02 e me retorna a pesquisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como proceder para, ao clicar no botão MARCAR da TELA 02, retornar para a **TELA 01 PASSO 02**? Neste caso, O GILBERTO IRIA APARECER NO espaço em branco na tela 01.

Comment: Já trabalhou alguma vez com DataTables? De uma olhada abaixo neste link:
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html Aqui você pode buscar os dados na própria tela apenas pesquisando.
Veja se pode adaptar. Abraços

Comment: Boa tarde.. @Leandro Azevedo.. Eu ate entendi o link que tu passou, mas acho que pela minha falta de experiencia não vi como ele se encaixaria na resolução do problema de voltar a pagina anterior. Para montar o DataTables teria que ser da mesma forma como faço hoje.. e quando chegasse na TELA 02 e apertar MARCAR ????????  Essa é a questão: VOLTAR com A TABLE JA PRONTA do jeito que estava.  Como falei e reitero aqui posso não ter visto a solução no link que tu postou pela falta de experiencia em php. Abraços.

Comment: Olá, você esta trabalhando com PHP nessas telas?

Comment: ola :) @Leandro Azevedo... Me desculpem todos.. Acho que realmente não mencionei as ferramentas que utilizo.. HTML... PHP e scripts JS. Abraços

Answer (score 0):

A sua questão pode ser resolvida por javascript / html5.
Esta é a solução que eu implementaria: a tela 2 seria modal(abriria em cima de tela 1). Quando o usuário clickar no botão os dados necessários na tela 1 seriam lidos na tela dois e populados os campos respetivos na tela 1. Se alguma informação tiver que ser gravada no servidor, pode fazer por ajax.

Link para construir uma janela modal:
https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Outra solução seria usar cookies ou web storage.

Comment: Boa tarde @Manuel Gerardo Pereira.. Obrigado pela atenção. Muito maneiro esse lance de MODAL... Eu não conhecia.  Estou lendo para ver a viabilidade no todo.. Assim que entender ele e conseguindo algo ou não conseguindo.. retorno a você.. Mais uma vez obrigado pela atenção. :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma sessão PHP

Página 1:

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['valor1'] = $valor1;
```

Chamar valor na página 2:

```
session_start() //inicia sessao
echo $_SESSION['valor1']; // Valor já pode ser solicitado
```